# Load large bitmap into byte array

Tags: java, android, arrays, bitmap, heap-memory

I am getting an OOM error from loading a large bitmap using BitmapFactory.decodeResource. I have seen other suggestions about compressing the image but for my app, preserving quality is absolutely necessary. Eventually I need to get the image into a byte/pixel array. Is there any way to get all of the pixels into an array without having to reduce quality or 'tile' the bitmap?

Also, I don't need to keep the bitmap, only the byte array (or an array of pixels). The code I'm writing will search the array. It will all eventually be implemented into a more complex app (written by someone else, hence my inexperience with android).

Comment: How big an image are we talking about, and how much memory is the rest of your app using?

Comment: Why not treat the bitmap file as a file and use more traditional methods of reading it with `FileInputStream` and the like?

Comment: At the moment the app isn't using any. It is a 3.5mb jpeg (3200x2500). When saved as a bmp it comes out to nearly 25mb. Perhaps I should uncompress it in memory?

Comment: @TheCapn would it work to create a FileInputStream and then read 3/4 bytes at a time for each pixel? I was unaware of FileInputStream.

Comment: You will make a loop where you read a reasonable amount from the input stream, say 65534 bytes, and add to the byte array until done. Don't fiddle around with 4 bytes as it slows all down.

Comment: thanks. That seems to have worked!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at android's documentation on handling large bitmaps http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: I have but I need the full scaled version of the image. I'm working with some rudimentary image recognition(similar to looking for barcodes) and so pixel quality is necessary.

Comment: Yes. But since at the moment all my app does is load a bitmap (its a basic helloworld that I'm using to test my code) I didn't think that would make any difference.

Comment: you have to understand that every device is going to have different memory, you can try to recycle the bitmap after you get the byte array, but you will probably have to downsample the image whether you like it or not..